# bind method while quiting the windowsTK python

Tags: python, events, binding

I'm using tkinter for gui python. i want to add method when I press the button X , I mean when I click 'X' button it says bye (not dialogBox) and then quit

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this sample will answer at your question :

```
from tkinter import *

    master = Tk()

def callback():
    text= Label(master, text="Bye").pack()
    master.destroy()

b = Button(master, text="X", command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

But we don't have time to see 'Bye'... to see it, we should add a countdown to execute destroy after x sec (read about : after())